# Python - insert into ms access table

Tags: python, ms-access, sql-insert, pyodbc

I am able get some data from the ms access by some query, but I am not able to store data into any table, for example:

```
import sys, os, pyodbc

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:/Users/vlcek/Desktop/pokusdb.accdb;'
    )
connection = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)


cursor = connection.cursor()

sql="Insert into people (user_id, Name, Surname) values (27, 'Peter','Jackson')"

cursor.execute(sql)
```

I do have the table "people" already in database...

I am getting this output, I don't know, if it relevant:

The thread 'MainThread' (0x30e4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The program '[9696] python.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Thank you for your help,

Vaclav

Comment: Code 0 generally means that a process completed without any errors. Are you finding that the `INSERT` did not work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to commit your changes.

Add

```
connection.commit()
```

to the end of your code.