# How can read the list output and load into ms access?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-access, pycharm, pypyodbc

If anyone can help with the python script

My output is list format which I need to insert  into ms access.
I achieve the list from the below python script.

```
import csv
import urllib
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

FILE = 'Sample.csv'
def finance_manager(file):
sum = 0
transactions = []
with open(file, mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # get name, amount, currency
        name = row[1]
        amount = float(row[3])
        date = row[2]
        transaction = (name, date, amount)
        sum += amount
        transactions.append(transaction)
print(f"The sum of your transactions this month is {sum}")
print(' ')
return transactions
print(finance_manager(FILE))
access_string =(
    r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
    r"DBQ= C:\Users\User1\Documents\DatabaseSample.accdb")
cnnurl = "access+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(access_string)}"
acc_engine = create_engine(cnnurl)
```

The result list :
print(finance_manager(FILE))
[image]

Comment: You want to insert data into Access table, I think need to establish connection and run INSERT action SQL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976146/python-insert-into-ms-access-table and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058984/insert-multiple-rows-into-db-with-python-list-of-tuples

Answer (score 0):

I suggest working the other way round: From Access, you can easily establish a connection to a csv-file. You already have your Sample.csv, so let a (temporary) table in Access point to this file. Right-mouse-click -> Import -> Textfile -> Then select the file and last option to connect. In Access, you could perform the next steps, like copying the data into a destination-table. (E.g. call a Query from python) So you can reuse Sample.csv without losing data.