# Is there a limit on the number of connections opened from a client's side to a SQL Server database?

Tags: python, sql-server, database, pyodbc

I'm working on a Python application with an SQL Server database using `pyodbc`, and I need to open multiple connections from the application's side to the database.

I learnt that the max number of connections allowed on an instance of the SQL Server database is [32,767](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-connections-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15). My understanding is this is the max that the DB instance "can handle", i.e. all simultaneous users combined.

Is there a limit on how many connections **one** client can open towards the same database instance, is it also 32,767? If yes, where / how is this limit configured?

Comment: May I ask why is this a concern? The number you mention is mostly a theoretical limit as the id for the connection is probably represented by a 16 bit integer. I doubt many use cases reach a number of connections close to that. Specially when you consider that most client side connection will use some form of connection pooling.

Comment: Are you considering opening thousands of connections from a single client? You will likely run out of ephemeral TCP ports on the client.

Comment: @FernandoSibaja Thank you Fernando for the question and comment! I'm working on a PoC and there weren't many design thinking put into it, I was trying to use the same db connection & same cursor with threading to insert multiple records, but I was getting some 'connection is busy' errors. I think this is resolved by adding `MARS_Connection=yes` in the connection string. Great idea to look at connection pooling! Thank you.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you for the reply Dan! Excellent point about the TCP ports, I was planning to open multiple connections with threading inside loops, it wouldn't have reached 10K, I wanted to know for sure and couldn't find anything online. After the replies here I think my idea was gonna become a hot mess, thank you for guiding me away from it! I was getting a "connection is busy" error with only one connection & one cursor, this is now resolved enabling MARS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking an educated guess here that there is no connection count limit on the client side towards the same DB instance, there is a limit of 32,767 on the server side, but the client would be more likely to run out of other resources way before it gets close to this figure.

I was using one connection, one cursor, and threading to insert multiple records, but kept getting a "connection is busy" error, this is resolved by adding "MARS_Connection=yes" in the pyodbc database connection string, thanks to this [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-server-native-client-odbc-driver).

Related:

1. [How costly is opening and closing of a DB connection?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16973/140802)
2. [Can I use multiple cursors on one connection with pyodbc and MS SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573724/can-i-use-multiple-cursors-on-one-connection-with-pyodbc-and-ms-sql-server)